# How do I zoom my map using Google Maps API v3 when I click a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I can't get to Google Maps API v3 to zoom in/out when I click my hyperlink. I had it working in v2:

```
<a href="javascript:map.setCenter(new GLatLng(58.37,62.66), 16);map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);" >Some Place</a>
```

In v3 I have tried:

```
<a href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(58.37,62.66));">Some Place</a>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In v3, you have to call `setZoom` as well:

```
<a href="javascript:map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(58.37,62.66));map.setZoom(16);">Some Place</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. But
Error: TypeError: map.setCenter is not a function
Source File: javascript:map.setCenter(new%20google.maps.LatLng(58.37,62.66));map.setZoom(16);
Line: 1

Comment: Then there are errors in the code you didn't post. Also make sure that your "map" variable  is defined globally.